# Customize where components within the composite components will be placed in the webpage

Tags: jsf, facelets, composite-component

Is it possible to specify where the components within a composite component will be displayed on your webpage?

I have a composite component with a label and a textbox in it. I would like to know if I can specify to have the label be displayed on a div with id "label" and the textbox will be displayed inside another div with id "componentsContainer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Also, the composite component accounts in end as a **single** component anyway.

Closest what you can get is templating using `<ui:define>` and `<ui:insert>`, but that does likely not suit the functional requirement you had in mind while developing the composite component.

Comment: aw ok dude.  thanks much.  that's all i need to know.  will also try to look into that ui:define and ui:insert tags.